# Cypress cant reach web application (only sometimes)

Tags: cypress

I have installed a fresh VueJS project and followed the setup steps. I have chosen to install Cypress.

Now, when I run a pretty simple test to visit the authentication page at `http://localhost:4173/auth/login` *sometimes* it gives me back a `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4173`.

If I try to visit `http://localhost:4173/auth/login` on my normal Chrome browser (without being on Cypress's one) everything works correctly - I get the expected page.

Here's my script to start the server:

```json
{
"scripts": {
    "test:e2e:dev": "start-server-and-test 'vite dev --port 4173' http://localhost:4173 'cypress open --e2e'",
  },
}
```

Here's my simple test:

```js
describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('assert user can login', () => {
    cy.visit('/auth/login')
  })
})
```

Why is it that sometimes it works and I can't connect to `http://localhost:4173/auth/login` even though I can connect from my local browser?

Output when running `npm run test:e2e:dev`:

```
/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/yarn run test:e2e:dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ start-server-and-test 'vite dev --port 4173' http://localhost:4173 'cypress open --e2e'
1: starting server using command "vite dev --port 4173"
and when url "[ 'http://localhost:4173' ]" is responding with HTTP status code 200
running tests using command "cypress open --e2e"


  VITE v4.3.9  ready in 233 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54622/devtools/browser/ea1f0dad-b821-411e-b566-a8353f33f659
Missing baseUrl in compilerOptions. tsconfig-paths will be skipped
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `host` in my `vite` app to be `0.0.0.0` works:

```json
    "test:e2e:dev": "start-server-and-test 'vite dev --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4173' http://0.0.0.0:4173 'cypress open --e2e'",
```

Then on my `cypress.config.ts` I need to update the `baseUrl` to be `http://0.0.0.0:4173`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    watchForFileChanges: false,
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.{cy,spec}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    baseUrl: 'http://0.0.0.0:4173',
  }
})
```